# Java web application (maven project) does not run from Eclipse IDE - "Exception occured executing command line" and permission denied to "js build.sh"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I run Linux Mint 21.3 x86_64, I use the Eclipse IDE (version 2023-12 (4.30.0)) for Java development. I have a Java application (Eclipse Scout) that was working until this morning.

I tried to run the application from the IDE by clicking on the icon ***Run -> [webapp] all***. This has always worked before by launching a Jetty server and a URL for accessing the application BUT now, a dialog is displayed saying:

> *"Launching [webapp] all" has encountered a problem*

When I click the details button in the dialog box, I get the following message/explanation:

> *Exception occurred executing command line.
> Cannot run program "/home/jd/eclipse-scout-workspace/ygapp/ygapp/run-configs/js build.sh" (in directory "/home/jd/eclipse-scout-workspace/ygapp/ygapp.ui.html"): error=13, Permission denied*

I have no idea why suddenly the **js build.sh** is behaving like this. I have read/write access to the file, so I am a bit confused. I've updated the project ***Maven -> Update Project*** several times but the problem persists.

Can anyone please help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Does it not fail from the command line (Terminal) outside of Eclipse? Do you have full permission, including execute, over the "js" file?

Comment: I have full permission. I'm the only user and the admin of the system. I'm trying to run the application from inside Eclipse.